# I want np.meshgrid to take a whole array as input not its component

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have a set of data as such

```
a=[a1,a2,a3,..an]
b=[b1,........bn]
.
.
.
h=[h1.........hn]
```

Where a1...hn are arrays this type :

```
ai=np.array(xa1,xa2,xa3)
```

I'm using np.meshgrid to avoid using nested for loops:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
   for j
.
.
.        for x in range(len(h)):
```

Since itertools.product seems to take more time, I tried np.meshgrid to try get the cartesian product, only the result i want is :

```
[a1,b1,c1...h1]
[a1,b1......h2]
```

But I get I cartesian product of the component of each one like this:

```
[xa1,xa2,xa3,xa4.....xh3,xh4]
[xa1,xa2,xa3,xa4.....xh4,xh3]
```

I know my explanation wasn't clear enough, but can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks.

Comment: itertools.product is very fast, it's the correct translation of nested loops, and it cannot be a bottleneck in your implementation. The problem is probably that your code runs in `O(n**8)` time... if whatever np.meshgrid command you gave was faster, that's probably because it's returning a much smaller set of combinations (which you say is not what you want)